# Add a user to a resource group in Azure

Tags: azure

I have 2 subscriptions in Azure (subA and subB).
SubB has a lot of resource groups.
User John has access to subscriptions SubA and SubC.
I want to add user John to a resource group (resourceG_A) which belongs to subscriptions subB (that the user doesn't have). I want that John has access to perform some tasks in resourceG_A, such as start, stop VM. But this user sould not be able to see/access other VMs in other resource groups that belong to subscription subB.
What would be the better way to do it using the portal ?

Answer (score 0):

you can grant your user permissions on the resource group (such as virtual machine contributor) that would make sure he can only control virtual machines inside the resource group only

using portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Comment: Done that. User doesn´t have anything in azure portal. Do i have to send him any invitations or something like that?

Comment: no, user should relogin after you granted those permissions. another possibility why users sees nothing - global subscription filters

Comment: We tried that but the user doesn't have the new subscription in the portal. I also tried to send him invitation but also he doesn't receive the email. any idea why?

Comment: Fixed by spending him then invitation URL